# Pop-up login browser , spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a application configured using Spring Security.
I don't have a login page, so I use the browser pop-up to log the users, the pop-up works fine unless for the Cancel button, that reload the page instead of close the dialog.

I am using xml configuration.

Is there any configuration that I can use, to prevent it ? Spring, JS, or something else ?

[image: Screen with pop-up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found that if I instead of use the **BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint** directly, extend it and override two of it methods, I could set the return that I wanted and it would solve my problem. That was the page reloading the login pop-up every time that the user clicked sur the Cancel button.

```
@Component
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx) throws IOException  {
        //Header response
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

        //Error Status, that you want to return, 401, 404, ....
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        //Message that will be showed at screen
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setRealmName("NO MATTER WICH NAME");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

I configured it at my security-context.xml, inside < http >, but you can do the same at code level.

```
<http-basic entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
```